# Detect serialization type

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization, woocommerce

I'm trying to read the item attributes stored in a woocommerce database, I get a string stored in field "_product_attributes" like this:

"a:1:{s:5:"Sizes";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:5:"sizes";s:5:"value";s:5:"S|M|L";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation"; i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}}"

this is a serialized structure stored in database, i need to detect what tipe of serializacion is aplied in this case to create the list of attibutes for my program. i can do that in c# or in vb.net. thanks for all.

Comment: You might want look at getting WooCommerce.net.  Does all the serialisation/de-serialisations for you

Comment: What do you mean with 'type of serialization'?

Comment: What kind of format is this. It's not JSON as far as I can judge.